# How to get git files/directory tree structure in php?

Tags: php, html, git

I have a public git repository (bitbucket) containing some zip files contained in some directories.
I want to create a php page showing a download button for each zip, allowing to download it without having to get into bitbucket.

This can be done copying every zip url and creating a proper htlm button for it, but what i really want is not a static page, but a php page that autopopulate herself with the zip files currently present on the git repository, for it is growing fast and i don't want to update each time my page manually.

It is possibile? Sorry for the lack of code, but i don't really know where to start to.

Comment: Are those zip files releases of anything? If yes, you should probably set up a proper release process rather than storing them in the repository.

Comment: They are releases of a number of separated project. There are a number of directory, one for project and each project owner has a system to share a new release, as he likes, in form of a zip files that gets added to the main repository in his directory. I need a page showing available releases and download. What do you mean exactly for "proper release process"?

Comment: Instead of having the releases in the repository, provide them for download in a separate area. That way, you also get a much smaller repo in case you want to clone it completely.

Comment: Yes, i could put them in a online space, without using a git repo, but this is not what i'm asking for. Files must have their own repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the API from bitbucket to list all the files in a repo, then iterate the json to find all the zip files. check out https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Version+1 for detailed information about the API

Edit: in particular calling this link shows repo folder structure

```
https://bitbucket.org/!api/1.0/repositories/<username>/<repo_name>/directory/
```

Comment: Exactly what i was searching for. Thank you very much!! I added the full link of the api needed to solve the problem in your answer, for the next people needing it.